# Unable to find package virtual box for archlinux

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux

I was unable to run `pacman -S virtualbox`, all mirrors would return 404 so I upgraded my mirror list from this page https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/ and I'm still unable to find the package.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Have you try to download it directly from Oracle OTN site?

Comment: I tried this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) but when I run the all distribution installer, it says it can't find my Linux distribution.

I also tried to install virtualbox-bin from AUR, which was working fine until I tried to run a VM, I'm missing `vboxdvr`

Comment: Have you check where is installed vboxdvr and set PATH to this directory?

Comment: It seems that `virtualbox-bin` package from AUR does not include vboxdvr.

When the error occurs within virtualbox, it asks me to run a file in /etc/init.d but I don't have a such folder.

modprobe can't find the vboxdvr neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pacman cannot find the package on any mirror, that means it's looking for an old package that no longer exists, because your local package database is out-of-date. You should upgrade your system using `pacman -Syu` and do it more often.

Comment: Great advice, I'll tell you if that fix it but I think you got it thanks ! (I'll check it as accepted answer as soon as virtualbox is installed :) )